# Need CSV data set with normally distributed column variable, to compare to known mean (requirements)

Tags: data-request

I have literally been searching for such a dataset for two days. And I am going NUTS over this. I hope this type of question is welcome here.

I have an assignment that requires that I do a one-sample t-test on a normally distributed variable (generally known to be a normal distribution, with a reference), comparing that to a known/published mean. I need to provide links to the expectation of normality, the dataset, and the expected mean.

Other than that, it can be anything. Three links required.

Sounds simple.  Uhg.

I would go to the store and weigh 30 pears if the assignment allowed me to do that. And I would have been done with the entire assignment within 1 hour.

Comment: Two views in 1 hour.  One of the views, or both, was mine.

Comment: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php

Comment: I saw that.  From what I saw going through it, it doesn't have what I need.

Comment: Six views in 16 hours.  I spoke with the instructor, and he's fine with me taking measurements of 20+ items.

Answer (score -1):

Six post views in 16 hours.  Just a warning to others.

I spoke with the instructor, and I can take my own measurements of 20+ items.